# Real Python random percentage

Tags: python, random

I don't understand this syntax i have found in the real python book and was hoping I could get some clarity.

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random

total_A_wins = 0
total_B_wins = 0

trials = 100000
for trial in range(0, trials):
    A_win = 0
    B_win = 0
    if random() < .87: # 1st region
        A_win += 1
    else:
        B_win += 1
    # determine overall election outcome
    if A_win > B_win:
        total_A_wins += 1
    else:
        total_B_wins += 1

print "Probability A wins:", total_A_wins/trials
print "Probability B wins:", total_B_wins/trials
```

So in the exercise they state that A has an 87% chance of winning. But how does random () < .87 define that A would get the 87%?

When I read it it states:
if random is less than .87

This is what I was hoping to clarify because random being less than .87 doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The return value of `random.random()` is uniformly distributed across the range [0.0, 1.0) (so from 0.0 inclusive to 1.0 exclusive), so it has a equal chance of hitting any value in that range.

That means that 87% of the time, values below .87 are chosen.

If you were to change this to a test for `random() < 1.0`, that test would pass *always*, 100% of the time. If you would change it to `random() < 0.0`, it'd never pass, so 0% of the time. And since the distribution is uniform, `random() < 0.5` would be `True` half of the time, since the other half of the time values in the range [0.5, 1.0) would be picked instead.

You could look at it as a dice roll; 100% of the time, you'll roll a value < 7 with a standard 6-sided dice. 0% of the time you'll roll a value < 1, 50% of the time you'll roll a value < 4 (1, 2 or 3), and 66.67% of the time you'd roll a value less than 5 (so 2/3rds of all your rolls). The `random.random()` return value just has a *much* larger range than just 6 distinct values.

Comment: Had same question after seen how `statsd` client limits send rate: https://github.com/jsocol/pystatsd/blob/1c90b9fdf322680e2625da659abc2aa5d79b5bff/statsd/client/base.py#L63-L64 - thanks for answer